# How to create Symfony project from console, but still using Symfony plugin in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

When I create Symfony project from PhpStorm I can use these (and other) settings, like create new Symfony Controller:

[image]

But when I create Symfony project from console and open folder with PhpStorm, I can't use them.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you activated the Symfony plugin for such project? AFAIK it needs activation on per-project basis.

Comment: The plugin is active globally, how to activate it for current project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must activate plugin Symfony PHPStorm like that for each project :

[image]